# Select certain data and insert them

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, postgresql

I have a database in SQL Server 2008 and another similar database in Postgres. I am planning to develop one windows application using C# that will select 100 rows of data from `TableA` of SQL Server and insert into `TableA` in Postgres. I want to continue this process until all the data of Table A are inserted.

I can use this query to select 100 rows at a time.

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM TableA;
```

But how to loop until all the data are inserted?

Comment: Why would you do this instead of `INSERT INTO tableB SELECT * FROM tableA;` ?

Comment: @CraigRinger: Because I want to migrate my database from MS SQL Server to Postgres. I have similar database structure in both server. So, I want to select from TableA of Ms SQL Server and insert into TableA of Postgres.

Comment: I missed the cross-database nature. Sorry. Consider using a dedicated data migration tool for this. For fetching data until there is no more, you can use a *cursor* ... but dealing with concurrent updates/inserts/deletes is going to be hard, you'd need a full table lock.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0;i < row_Count;i=i+100)
{
string s = "SELECT * FROM TableA where index BETWEEN " + (i+1).ToString + "AND" + (i+100).ToSTring;
// use "s" as your query
}
```

Here, it is assumed that your table is indexed and starts from 1.

I am not sure this will work as it is, but it may give you some idea to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping select query try to use ResultSet stream using [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The DataReader provides an unbuffered stream of data that allows procedural logic to efficiently process results from a data source sequentially. The DataReader is a good choice when retrieving large amounts of data because the data is not cached in memory